# Change sitecode SCCM agent on Linux

Tags: linux, sccm

Is there any solution to change the SCCM agent sitecode for a Linux client without reinstalling it?

I found a vbs script for windows client [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Change-sccm-configmgr-cf6e0327/view/Discussions#content)

But nothing for Linux.

I've tried seding sitecode with the new one in all XML files under `/opt/microsoft/` without results, the agent got broken, of course.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting any file on this **/opt/microsoft/configmgr** path which has config details and target the SITE CODE details change it(Take backup of it before modify any details) and then refresh the services and check.